# CreateProcess causing problems

Tags: c, winapi

for some reason create process opens cmd
even when its not specified
and pressing enter causes more instances of cmd to popup in the command line.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    char cmdline[255];

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    loop:
         fgets(cmdline,255,stdin);
         CreateProcessA(NULL,cmdline,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
         goto loop;
}
```

Comment: `cmd` in your code is obviously a variable filled with user input.  Does "cmd" in your question refer to this variable, or to `cmd.exe` ?

Comment: I guess if you debug your program you'd understand why it behaved as it does. Have you debugged your program?

Comment: The only way a command window would appear is if your `cmd[]` variable receives a command string from the user that invokes a console app.  If you don't want a command window to appear for console apps, `CreateProcess()` does have a `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag available.

Comment: The string will contain a `\n`, is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `fgets` will get a string with charactor '\n' when size of inserted string <(255-1). So, let's set the `\n` to `\0`:

```
fgets(cmd, 255, stdin);
cmd[strlen(cmd) - 1] = '\0';
CreateProcess(cmd, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Second,

> more instances of cmd to popup in the command line.

If what you mean is like:

[image]

This is because the input focus of the cmd process and the current process alternately appears in the same console, not always creating a new instance.

If you `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`:

```
CreateProcess(cmd, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

You will see that only a new cmd console has been created.
[image]